# Настройка ЧПУ .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Есть ссылки вида test.com/index.php?page=page2 
Нужно чтобы было так: test.com/page2
Как это сделать с помощью .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=page$1
```

Comment: А если у меня много ссылок вида index.php?page=page2, index.php?page=about, index.php?page=contact  и т.д ? Т.е мне нужно оставить только то что после "="

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?page=page$1